# selecting alpha numeric node in XQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery-sql

i have this XQuery

declare @XML xml

```
set @XML = 
'
<root>
  <row1>
    <value>1</value>
  </row1>
  <1row2>
    <value>2</value>
  </1row2>
</root>
'

select @XML.query('/root/1row2')
```

i keep on getting an error white trying to select 1row2.

this error

```
XQuery [query()]: Syntax error near '1', expected a step expression.
```

is seems that i just keep getting this error when xml node start with a number is there a way to select the said node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [XML Naming Rules](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp), XML elements must follow these naming rules:

- Element names are case-sensitive
- Element names must start with a letter or underscore
- Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and
  periods
- Element names cannot contain spaces
- Any name can be used, no words are reserved (except xml).

So, the elements names must start with a letter or underscore. On `SQL Server 2016 SP1` your XML is event not a valid and cannot be executed:

[image]

You need to either repair your string to be a valid XML or to query the data using some other technique (for example, SQL CLR function to implement regex expression support or splitting the nodes).